# Redirect the output using `sudo`

Tags: command-line, sudo

I have a small question regarding using `sudo` with output redirect `>`. To enable IP forwrding, someone can use the command:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Executing this command will give permission denied as it requires root privileges. However, executing the same command with `sudo` gives also permission denied error! It seems that output redirect `>` does not inherit the permissions of the preceding command `echo`. Is this right?

As a workaround I do:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Is this the best way to do it? Am I missing something?

Please, note that this is an example and it applies to all commands that use output redirect.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your approach with `sudo tee` is fine. A nice consequence of using `sudo tee` is that the executed command before the pipe will not run as root. That's useful if you just need the output of a program, which does not require root privileges.

If you don't care about the output of the program used before the pipe (`echo 1` in this case), redirect stdout to `/dev/null`:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward > /dev/null
```

The above is equivalent to `sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'` with the difference that `echo 1` is run as root.

If you need to append to a privileged file, you can either use `sh -c 'echo 127.0.0.1 local.host >> /etc/hosts'` or:

```
echo 127.0.0.1 local.host | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Note the `-a` which is shorthand for `--append`.

Answer (score 9):

One solution is to use :

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
```

but this one doesn't inherit env properties from the parent shell, so you can't use it for example with `echo $PATH` to get the same result you'd have in your parent shell (of course only in case you alter your path property) .

Using `sudo -E` will preserve the environment variables.

Also, according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh, you'd be better off using `sh` (which is a symlink to `dash`), instead of invoking this with `bash`.

So, you might rewrite this as :

```
sudo -E sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
```

Comment: You don't need bash for this job, you'd better to use sh (symlink to dash). See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh for differences between these.

Comment: Using "sudo -E" will preserve the environment variables.

Comment: @Lekensteyn You're right sh will do it for this command, but occasionally a command a user runs behaves differently due to bash's additional functionality. I think it's reasonable to recommend bash for users who don't know about the differences. The linked documentation does *not* say sh should be used instead of bash for interactive purposes.

Comment: @EliahKagan What command have you seen go wrong when using `sh -c` instead of `bash -c`? Granted, `bash` has features which are incompatible with dash (some forms of variable expansion or brace-globbing for example), but in most cases you will at most have a simple redirection. I do not recommend `sh` for interactive purposes (input/response), for that `bash` is better suited.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use the `sudo bash -c` trick, or just do `sudo -s` first to stay root, then run the redirection command.

The reason it doesn't work the first way is that the shell processes the redirection first, then runs `sudo`.  Since your shell doesn't have access to the file, the redirection fails.