# Why does echoing these parameters with sudo not work?

Tags: command-line, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sudo & redirect output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20578/sudo-redirect-output)

These are suggestions given by powertop to save energy:

```
echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs

echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

However, I cannot execute them from terminal even as sudo. Ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your command doesn't work because the redirection `> file` is done by the current shell *prior* to the execution of the command, so before the sudo is in effect.

There is a command, called `tee`, that writes to a file and to stdout what it receives on its stdin: this is handy to write something to a file without redirection. If the file can be modified only by root, it is sufficient to prepend `sudo` to `tee`.

```
echo 1500 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
```

Another way to obtain the desired result, mantaining the redirection, is to move the redirection to a subshell executed by root, through `sudo`:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs'
```

Lastly, you can enter a root shell in various ways, and you remain root until you `exit` explicitly that shell:

```
sudo su
sudo -s
sudo bash
```

For more information see the manuale pages of `sudo`, `su` and of course of `bash`.

Comment: I always forget about tee :-X +1 tomorrow ;) and dago: accept this one please instead of mine. it is shorter and a better answer.

Comment: Gentlem, as a beginner thanks but still a load of questions. I know hoe to make a script executable but what is the difference to do sudo su before and how? wHAT is the sudo tee or sudo sh - c

Comment: I will give more information in the answer

Answer (score 9):

Instead of creating a cronjob for setting values as described by [@Seppo Erviälä](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50242/how-to-save-power-saving-suggestions-made-by-powertop/50328#50328), you can make use of the configuration files of `procps` and `sysfsutils`.

#### /proc/sys

Values for `/proc/sys` can be set in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`. To make `echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs` persistent, add a line with:

```
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 1500
```

To load the changes in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to the current session, run:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

#### /sys

For setting values in `/sys` the package `sysfsutils` needs to be installed. The configuration file is located at `/etc/sysfs.conf`. To make `echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save` persistent, add a line with:

```
module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save = 1
```

To apply the values in `/etc/sysfs.conf` to the current session, run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sysfsutils restart
```

Comment: Thanks for info, this seems much more proper way to do this

Answer (score 2):

Do a `sudo -s` or a `sudo su` first:

[image]

From a script:

```
# more powersave
echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
# ./powersave 
#
```

Best practice would be to ussue the `sudo -s` before activating the script (hence the #).

Comment: Thanks, of course you earned a voting up and solved, however, how can I use this in a script together with other power saving measures? BTW what is the difference between sudo su and command and sudo command?

Comment: Toss the lines in a script, make it executable and run sudo su before activating the script.

Comment: ... or run each line with "sudo -i " immediately before the echo statements

Comment: worked on my test program - also see @enzotib answer for an alternate

Comment: @Rinzwind Using a root shell is not a "best practice" in Ubuntu. To allow writing to privileged locations using redirection operators, see http://askubuntu.com/q/20578/6969

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: See answer by  [@Lekensteyn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50242/how-to-save-power-saving-suggestions-made-by-powertop/50332#50332) for more proper way to edit `/proc/sys` and `/sys` defaults.

Running these suggestions from command line will only enable them for your current session and they will reset to defaults after a reboot. If you want to enable these suggestions each time your system starts you should make them into a script:

```
#!/bin/dash
echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

You can place this script somewhere convinient eg. `/root/power_save.sh`.

Then you want to make sure it runs with root privileges each time your system starts. This can be done with `sudo crontab -e` which opens list of time based tasks for root. Add line:

```
@reboot /root/power_save.sh
```

Don't forget to make your script executable:

```
sudo chmod u+x /root/power_save.sh
```

This way these power saving options will be enabled for all users, even before login, and no password is needed to authorize them each time.