# How to disable auto power off of usb devices like usb mouse?

Tags: usb, mouse, power-management, powernap

I don't know how , but somehow automatic power-off of usb devices got accidentally enabled. Now my usb mouse goes off even if it's idle for 2-3 seconds. It's really irritating.

This happened after I installed `powertop` and `powernap`. Maybe it has something to do with these two applications.

How can I disable this "feature"?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's *PowerNap* that's doing this.

You can disable just this part of PowerNap's power savings scripts with:

```
sudo powernap-action --disable usb_autosuspend
```

Comment: For me in debian jessie (8.4) it was laptop mode. See answer below. Writing to `/sys/bus/usb/devices/«device»/power/level` also worked, see other answer.

Answer (score 37):

Just copy paste the following command in terminal and it will disable auto suspending.

Disabling auto suspending USB

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend >/dev/null
```

Disable USB autosuspend

```
echo on | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level >/dev/null
```

Comment: Disable USB autosuspend is exactly what I was looking for. Here I don't have powernap installed.

Comment: Same, I don't have powernap either. This worked for me.

Comment: Is that reboot-persistent ?

Comment: nope @Kwaio ... also have a look http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: How to make it reboot-persistent:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/73590/how-to-permanently-save-powertops-suggestions?rq=1

Comment: What is this difference between the two scripts? Do I need both or only one of them?

Comment: I would recommend the use of tlp. @rosencreuz

Comment: @rosencreuz http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: I had to change line 2 to ```do sudo sh -c "echo on > $foo";```

Comment: Just do sudo su , before you do anything.... be root @laertiades

Comment: Works, but converting from device number given by `lsusb`, and number in `/sys/bus/usb/devices`, is hard. I see no relationship. The bus number is the same, then I just poke around looking for a matching manufacturer:device ID.

Comment: We need to run both commands. It works !!

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 `kern.log` says: `WARNING! power/level is deprecated; use power/control instead`

Answer (score 11):

Could it be that laptop mode tools are causing this? If so, try the following:

1. *Optional:* Create a backup of `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf` by copying it in your home folder:

   ```
   cp /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf ~/usb.autosuspend.old
   ```
2. Get the USB ID of your mouse/keyboard

   ```
   lsusb
   ```

   This will return a list including `ID xxxx:xxxx` for your mouse/keyboard.
3. Edit the original `usb-autosuspend.conf`

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf
   ```
4. There will be an entry called `AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST=''` change this to `AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST='xxxx:xxxx'`
5. This should stop your USB mouse/keyboard from being suspended. Now you either need to restart your computer or restart laptop-mode using

   ```
   sudo service laptop-mode restart
   ```

*Source: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/06/fix-usb-mouse-not-working-laptop-mode-tools-ubuntu/*

Comment: You find your ID with the command `lsusb|grep -i mouse|sed 's/^.* ID //g'|sed 's/ .*$//g'` (assuming there is the word "mouse" in the string for your mouse) If you don't find out the ID of your mouse, use `watch -d lsusb` while you plug in your mouse.

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 15.04, this file has been moved to `runtime-pm.conf` and the line to add the id to is now called `AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_BLACKLIST=""`. Strangely, I couldn't get my blacklist to work so I just disabled this module by setting `CONTROL_RUNTIME_AUTOSUSPEND=0`. It worked!

Comment: It worked on Debian Jessie (8.4), but file is `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf`

Comment: You were spot on, in my case I ran "lmt-config-gui" for Laptop Mode Tools and unchecked "Enable module runtime-pm".  This issue began after updating my KDE Neon kernel from 4.4 to 4.8 last night and was driving me bonkers! Thanks!

Comment: I didn't have laptop-mode installed (though something was suspending my USB) and when I did install `laptop-mode-tools` I didn't have the usb-autosuspend.conf (that was for 14.04 but I have 16.04). I did have a  `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf` per https://askubuntu.com/a/370406/318507 . Still waiting to see if this fixes the issue or if I have to track down what was originally suspending it.