# Mouse and touchpad freeze without power supply

Tags: kernel, power-management

I have a fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my HP ProBook.

My external mouse and touchpad freeze in battery mode, but I can reinitialize them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and back to <kbd>7</kbd>. As long as I move the mouse everything is fine. But not touching the mouse for one second will freeze it.

I could solve the problem for my touchpad putting these two lines into `rc.local`:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

But I have no solution for my external wired mouse. How to fix it?

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse

Comment: I once had a similar issue, the cause was that the battery was broken and replacing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you:

```
sudo apt-get install powernap
sudo powernap-action --disable usb_autosuspend
```

solved my problem!