# External HD keeps disconnecting, And wont auto mount

Tags: mount, hard-drive, unmount

So i've read through other questions but cant find a solution..

I have an externel drive in `/dev/sdg` and it continually disconnects..

I edited `/etc/fstab` so that it would auto mount but every time it disconnects the system reads it differently, for example it used to be `/dev/sdb` then `/dev/sdc` then `/dev/sdd` and so one... It remains mounted for quite some time. But when it unmounts I need to click on the file explorer and click on it again for it to mount. This makes it impossible for me to work with programs that continually read data from the drive.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Also I'm curious as to what drive you are having a problem with?  I'm having the same issue with Seagate 4TB 3.5" external drives. It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the UUID of the drive, use the following command:

```
blkid
```

Use the UUID of the drive in fstab instead of /dev/sdX. The UUID is static and should remain the same even when the device name changes.

Comment: Yeap I have UUID=`uid_here`

But it still gets unmounted like every 30 mins.

Comment: @Banned_User that sounds like a power-manager is disabling or "suspending" your USB connection. Check power-manager settings. If you have TLP installed, put it on the USB suspend blacklist. Powertop and powernap could also be responsible for this see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse

Comment: @Banned_User you can check your autosuspend settings for your USB devices for USB port #1 you would check this file: `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/autosuspend` the file should read "0". Do this for each of the other ports: `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/autosuspend` for port #2 and `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/autosuspend` for port #3 etc...

Comment: Mine read 0, but I still get disconnects every 30 minutes or so. I even added the UUID as a mounted drive, but I still have to remount the drives using sudo mount -a every 30 mins.