# how to make my Bluetooth USB adapter suspend, when my laptop suspends

Tags: usb, suspend, bluetooth

I currently have installed Xubuntu in my Asus s200E laptop and please note that I am still a beginner in Linux systems ( I know the really basics from my efforts to solve various little bugs at times).

My new problem is the following, while I have to mention that after searching for a considerable amount of time in the Internet I have not found a similar problem.

So, because my laptop did not have a Bluetooth adapter by its own,I bought a USB adapter, however I found that when I try to suspend my laptop with the adapter connected (either by closing the Lid or by manually selecting it) it does suspend but then it seems that the adapter forces the laptop to un-suspend because it never turns off.

It is similar when I  suspend it and then after 2 secs, I press a random key.

I was trying to somehow reach the power settings of the adapter but I did not have any luck.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off the USB power to my mouse, when I suspend the notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823318/how-to-turn-off-the-usb-power-to-my-mouse-when-i-suspend-the-notebook)

Comment: I've just updated the duplicate candidate with a simpler solution for powering off all USB devices without having to do a lot of extra research work on your part.