# mouse connected to the usb port stops working all of a sudden in ubuntu 16.x

Tags: 14.04, networking, 16.04, usb, mouse

mouse connected to the usb port stops working all of a sudden in **several** ubuntu machines. it does work properly on a reboot and for sometime, if I use the same mouse on a different ubuntu machine it works fine without any issues.

**In Ubuntu 16.x machine**

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 111: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6473 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

cat /etc/lsb-release
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"


tail -f /var/log/system.log
    Oct 17 13:08:51 athens kernel: [14061.770654] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:51 athens kernel: [14061.946661] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 90 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:51 athens kernel: [14062.018665] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:51 athens kernel: [14062.194671] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:52 athens kernel: [14062.370677] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 91 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:52 athens kernel: [14062.778683] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 91, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:52 athens kernel: [14062.850681] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 92 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:52 athens kernel: [14063.258678] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 92, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:52 athens kernel: [14063.258803] usb 2-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
    Oct 17 13:08:54 athens kernel: [14064.814760] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 93 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:54 athens kernel: [14064.886752] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:54 athens kernel: [14065.062771] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:54 athens kernel: [14065.238785] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 94 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:55 athens kernel: [14065.310767] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:55 athens kernel: [14065.486787] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:55 athens kernel: [14065.662792] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 95 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:55 athens kernel: [14066.070783] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 95, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:55 athens kernel: [14066.142793] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 96 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:56 athens kernel: [14066.550799] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 96, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:56 athens kernel: [14066.550913] usb 2-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
    Oct 17 13:08:57 athens kernel: [14068.122887] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 97 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:57 athens kernel: [14068.194886] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:58 athens kernel: [14068.370890] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:58 athens kernel: [14068.546898] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 98 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:58 athens kernel: [14068.618901] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:58 athens kernel: [14068.794905] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:58 athens kernel: [14068.970913] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 99 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:59 athens kernel: [14069.378902] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 99, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:59 athens kernel: [14069.450933] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 100 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:08:59 athens kernel: [14069.858936] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 100, error -32
    Oct 17 13:08:59 athens kernel: [14069.859191] usb 2-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
    Oct 17 13:09:01 athens kernel: [14071.431003] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 101 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:09:01 athens kernel: [14071.503003] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:09:01 athens kernel: [14071.679005] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:09:01 athens kernel: [14071.854953] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 102 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:09:01 athens kernel: [14071.926977] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:09:01 athens kernel: [14072.103026] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    Oct 17 13:09:01 athens kernel: [14072.279029] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 103 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:09:02 athens kernel: [14072.687020] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 103, error -32
    Oct 17 13:09:02 athens kernel: [14072.759023] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 104 using ehci-pci
    Oct 17 13:09:02 athens kernel: [14073.167061] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 104, error -32
    Oct 17 13:09:02 athens kernel: [14073.167294] usb 2-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

**In 14.x machine**

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 064e:8132 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"

grep usb /var/log/syslog
Oct 17 11:18:50 lisbon kernel: [ 4342.197299] usb 1-1.4: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:18:51 lisbon kernel: [ 4342.458863] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Oct 17 11:18:51 lisbon kernel: [ 4342.822666] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Oct 17 11:18:51 lisbon kernel: [ 4343.186450] usb 1-1.4: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:18:52 lisbon kernel: [ 4343.446268] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Oct 17 11:18:52 lisbon kernel: [ 4343.810095] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Oct 17 11:18:52 lisbon kernel: [ 4344.173889] usb 1-1.4: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:18:53 lisbon kernel: [ 4344.581661] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 6, error -32
Oct 17 11:18:53 lisbon kernel: [ 4344.841484] usb 1-1.4: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:18:54 lisbon kernel: [ 4345.249295] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 6, error -32
Oct 17 11:18:54 lisbon kernel: [ 4345.249982] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 6
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607268]  [<ffffffff81564df4>] usb_disconnect+0x54/0x2c0
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607274]  [<ffffffff8156e6c4>] ? usb_control_msg+0xd4/0x110
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607347] Workqueue: events hid_reset [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607422]  [<ffffffffc081e4fa>] usbhid_close+0x6a/0x120 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607514]  [<ffffffffc081e155>] usbhid_disconnect+0x55/0xa0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607520]  [<ffffffff815723e4>] usb_unbind_interface+0x74/0x2b0
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607533]  [<ffffffff815726a8>] usb_driver_release_interface+0x88/0x90
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607538]  [<ffffffff815726de>] usb_forced_unbind_intf+0x2e/0x60
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607548]  [<ffffffff815728a9>] usb_unbind_and_rebind_marked_interfaces+0x19/0x30
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607552]  [<ffffffff81564130>] usb_reset_device+0x1b0/0x2a0
Oct 17 11:22:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4557.607557]  [<ffffffffc081ca5f>] hid_reset+0x14f/0x1c0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540527]  [<ffffffff81564df4>] usb_disconnect+0x54/0x2c0
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540535]  [<ffffffff8156e6c4>] ? usb_control_msg+0xd4/0x110
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540629] Workqueue: events hid_reset [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540729]  [<ffffffffc081e4fa>] usbhid_close+0x6a/0x120 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540844]  [<ffffffffc081e155>] usbhid_disconnect+0x55/0xa0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540851]  [<ffffffff815723e4>] usb_unbind_interface+0x74/0x2b0
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540869]  [<ffffffff815726a8>] usb_driver_release_interface+0x88/0x90
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540876]  [<ffffffff815726de>] usb_forced_unbind_intf+0x2e/0x60
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540890]  [<ffffffff815728a9>] usb_unbind_and_rebind_marked_interfaces+0x19/0x30
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540894]  [<ffffffff81564130>] usb_reset_device+0x1b0/0x2a0
Oct 17 11:24:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4677.540902]  [<ffffffffc081ca5f>] hid_reset+0x14f/0x1c0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.473866]  [<ffffffff81564df4>] usb_disconnect+0x54/0x2c0
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.473873]  [<ffffffff8156e6c4>] ? usb_control_msg+0xd4/0x110
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.473962] Workqueue: events hid_reset [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.474053]  [<ffffffffc081e4fa>] usbhid_close+0x6a/0x120 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.474164]  [<ffffffffc081e155>] usbhid_disconnect+0x55/0xa0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.474171]  [<ffffffff815723e4>] usb_unbind_interface+0x74/0x2b0
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.474186]  [<ffffffff815726a8>] usb_driver_release_interface+0x88/0x90
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.474193]  [<ffffffff815726de>] usb_forced_unbind_intf+0x2e/0x60
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.474205]  [<ffffffff815728a9>] usb_unbind_and_rebind_marked_interfaces+0x19/0x30
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.474210]  [<ffffffff81564130>] usb_reset_device+0x1b0/0x2a0
Oct 17 11:26:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4797.474217]  [<ffffffffc081ca5f>] hid_reset+0x14f/0x1c0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407104]  [<ffffffff81564df4>] usb_disconnect+0x54/0x2c0
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407108]  [<ffffffff8156e6c4>] ? usb_control_msg+0xd4/0x110
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407159] Workqueue: events hid_reset [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407212]  [<ffffffffc081e4fa>] usbhid_close+0x6a/0x120 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407276]  [<ffffffffc081e155>] usbhid_disconnect+0x55/0xa0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407280]  [<ffffffff815723e4>] usb_unbind_interface+0x74/0x2b0
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407289]  [<ffffffff815726a8>] usb_driver_release_interface+0x88/0x90
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407292]  [<ffffffff815726de>] usb_forced_unbind_intf+0x2e/0x60
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407299]  [<ffffffff815728a9>] usb_unbind_and_rebind_marked_interfaces+0x19/0x30
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407302]  [<ffffffff81564130>] usb_reset_device+0x1b0/0x2a0
Oct 17 11:28:26 lisbon kernel: [ 4917.407306]  [<ffffffffc081ca5f>] hid_reset+0x14f/0x1c0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340382]  [<ffffffff81564df4>] usb_disconnect+0x54/0x2c0
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340388]  [<ffffffff8156e6c4>] ? usb_control_msg+0xd4/0x110
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340462] Workqueue: events hid_reset [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340536]  [<ffffffffc081e4fa>] usbhid_close+0x6a/0x120 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340625]  [<ffffffffc081e155>] usbhid_disconnect+0x55/0xa0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340630]  [<ffffffff815723e4>] usb_unbind_interface+0x74/0x2b0
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340643]  [<ffffffff815726a8>] usb_driver_release_interface+0x88/0x90
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340648]  [<ffffffff815726de>] usb_forced_unbind_intf+0x2e/0x60
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340658]  [<ffffffff815728a9>] usb_unbind_and_rebind_marked_interfaces+0x19/0x30
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340662]  [<ffffffff81564130>] usb_reset_device+0x1b0/0x2a0
Oct 17 11:30:26 lisbon kernel: [ 5037.340667]  [<ffffffffc081ca5f>] hid_reset+0x14f/0x1c0 [usbhid]
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic root=UUID=6c78f8ee-2337-4e3c-b3eb-027f589595e4 ro quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 vt.handoff=7
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic root=UUID=6c78f8ee-2337-4e3c-b3eb-027f589595e4 ro quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 vt.handoff=7
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    0.568907] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    0.568920] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    0.568947] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.393496] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.393498] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.393500] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.393502] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-70-generic ehci_hcd
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.393504] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.395215] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.395217] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.395219] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.395221] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-70-generic xhci_hcd
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.395223] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.398052] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.398054] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.398056] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.398058] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-70-generic xhci_hcd
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.398060] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.705326] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.837601] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    1.837605] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.109093] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.206043] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c077
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.206048] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.206050] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Optical Mouse
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.206052] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.212681] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.212684] usbhid: USB HID core driver
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.215356] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:046D:C077.0001/input/input6
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.215477] hid-generic 0003:046D:C077.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3/input0
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.277017] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.370206] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=0036
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.370210] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.440916] usb 1-1.7: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.533664] usb 1-1.7: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.533669] usb 1-1.7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.533671] usb 1-1.7: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.533673] usb 1-1.7: Manufacturer: Generic
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.533674] usb 1-1.7: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.540724] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtsx_usb
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.604834] usb 1-1.8: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.765944] usb 1-1.8: New USB device found, idVendor=064e, idProduct=8132
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.765947] usb 1-1.8: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.765949] usb 1-1.8: Product: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [    2.765950] usb 1-1.8: Manufacturer: SuYin
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [   12.502760] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [   12.893453] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [   12.897561] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 4
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [   13.098982] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [   13.841901] input: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.8/1-1.8:1.0/input/input13
Oct 17 11:52:06 lisbon kernel: [   13.841990] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
Oct 17 11:52:08 lisbon kernel: [   18.193469] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=0036
Oct 17 11:52:08 lisbon kernel: [   18.193475] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Oct 17 12:33:25 lisbon kernel: [ 2480.159910] usb 1-1.8: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 12:33:25 lisbon kernel: [ 2480.327829] usb 1-1.5: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 12:33:25 lisbon kernel: [ 2480.420098] usb 1-1.5: device firmware changed
Oct 17 12:33:25 lisbon kernel: [ 2480.491742] usb 1-1.7: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 12:33:25 lisbon kernel: [ 2480.588347] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 7
Oct 17 12:33:25 lisbon kernel: [ 2480.659639] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 12:33:25 lisbon kernel: [ 2480.752959] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=0036
Oct 17 12:33:25 lisbon kernel: [ 2480.752963] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Oct 17 12:33:26 lisbon kernel: [ 2480.948797] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 8
Oct 17 12:33:26 lisbon kernel: [ 2481.147332] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
Oct 17 12:33:31 lisbon kernel: [ 2486.237720] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=0036
Oct 17 12:33:31 lisbon kernel: [ 2486.237723] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Comment: Did you try installing Solaar, releasing the USB dongle from the mouse, and reconnecting? It also sounds like your mouse may be dying (batteries, maybe even connector). Finally, you may need to disable power saving or ACPI. See this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1028767.html

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the package laptop-mode-tools, it might come from the USB autosuspend feature (which shuts down some USB ports when they are unused, to save power).

A quick workaround is to uninstall it :

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
```

If it fixes your mouse issues, you might try to reinstall it, and fine-tune its configuration to disable USB autosuspend only for the mouse :

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

And then adjust the relevant config file, which depends on the version of your laptop-mode-tools package :

- For versions <1.66 (Ubuntu 14.04 has 1.64) : in `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf`, you might use `CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0` to completely disable autosuspend, or `AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST` to specify for which USB device(s) it should be disabled
- For versions >1.66 (Ubuntu 16.04 has 1.68) : in `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf`, you might use `CONTROL_RUNTIME_AUTOSUSPEND=0` to completely disable autosuspend, or `AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_BLACKLIST` to specify for which USB device(s) it should be disabled (see https://github.com/rickysarraf/laptop-mode-tools/blob/lmt-upstream/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf)

In both cases, a `lsusb` command should give you the relevant id. For example : `AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_BLACKLIST="046d:c051"` (several ids can be given whith space separator)

Comment: TLP default config does *not* autosuspend input devices, so no need to uninstall.

Comment: All right, I edited the answer. I was indeed unsure for tlp

Answer (score -1):

Not here for the bounty - since I have had a similar problem and found an answer on here :0 Look at the answer given by user 'Qasim' on this page.

The mouse cutting out may be usb power suspend related.

[How to disable auto power off of usb devices like usb mouse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse)

It may be worth a try.

Comment: This is comment-worthy, not answer-worthy.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try blowing into the USB on the mouse end, and the computer end.
2. Try another USB port on your computer.
3. Maybe your mouse is broken or is not compatible with your computer.

I'm happy to help more.

Comment: This is not an effective answer. Refrain from questions that may need commenting until you have sufficient reputation to comment.