# Mouse issues on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: usb, mouse, 17.04, idle

I seem to be running into some issues with my mouse on my new Ubuntu 17.04 installation.

It will work fine at first, but if I leave my computer idling it will have issues when I use my computer again.

It's a Wireless USB M185, and yes, the battery is fully charged and I have tried it on other computers, no problems on my 16.10 installation.

I appear to be able to get my mouse working again if I connect a Wi-Fi mouse to my PC and use my phone. I can return to my normal mouse after this until I let the machine idle again.

Here is some output from lsusb

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0102 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM106 Like Sound Device
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 148f:760b Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb`? Could you please try https://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse? I suspect that the mouse is put into power saving mode for some reason.

Comment: Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0102 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM106 Like Sound Device
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 148f:760b Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.