# Bluetooth mouse stops after a few seconds

Tags: 18.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have a Microsoft Arc bluetooth mouse I have always used with Ubuntu 18.04. After installing the system again, the mouse is presenting a very weird behavior:

- After connecting, it works (but a bit laggy) for a few seconds, and then it becomes completely unresponsive.
- The system still recognizes it as a connected device even when it is unresponsive.

I did change the batteries already but the problem persists. I can also connect it my phone and it works perfectly. Also tried all sorts of re-pairing and reboots, installed blueman but nothing seems to solve it.

How can I track what is going wrong? The problem is very consistent, so it has to show in some logs.

EDIT: I figured out it becomes unresponsive after a few seconds without doing any clicks. If I keep left-clicking the mouse keeps responding. After a few seconds without clicking it'll stop moving and clicking.

Comment: You should start with `dmesg -T` and see if there is anything there.

Comment: I was using `bluetoothctl` but found no hint of the problem in the info there, it'll act as if it was connected even when it's unresponsive. I'd like to know if there are some real-time data transfer monitoring solution so I can check if the device has stopped receiving the signal completely.

Comment: Check out this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195686/mouse-randomly-stops-responding-for-a-few-seconds or https://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse