# mouse randomly stops responding for a few seconds

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, mouse

I have been a Linux user for a number of years, and about a year on this very system I'm reporting for. It was running xubuntu perfectly up to about a week ago. I have automatic updates on it, and I believe it was after an update. Mouse just randomly stops working for a few seconds, you cannot move it nor click it. This can happen in succession for a number of times. It is so annoying, I would have reinstalled the whole thing if I did not have important work on it. I have verified it with a different mouse, and also tried Windows 10 that I have on dual boot. Windows does not have any problems.

It is the latest kernel on Ryzen 3 and GeForce 1070ti with proprietary drivers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a wireless mouse?

Comment: no, wired. i have tried two of them, same problem. o, and it happens more if i plug it into the computer directly. i usually plug it into the keyboard usb extension. i have one of those old microsoft keyboards that have two usb plugs on them, so i use that for convenience.

Comment: check out this https://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse

Comment: none of the usb autosuspend suggestions worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be a problem when GeForce graphics cards are present on an AMD machine. I looked into the kernel log, and there was a constant error

reset low-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd

I found the solution here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238367

Essentially, I added the following kernel parameter

amd_iommu=off

Since I did not have this problem before, and I have this graphics card for about a year, this must have been caused by a kernel update, but that is another story...