# Bluetooth mouse disconnect for 3 seconds after hibernation

Tags: bluetooth

After resuming from hibernation, my mouse will work fine for about 0.5~1 minute, then stop working for about 1~3 seconds, and then it will work again.

During the 3 seconds, I can see that on the top right corner, the Bluetooth icon disappear then appear.

Here is the log for bluetooth.service

```
$ journalctl -u bluetooth.service
```

It is fine until `Endpoint registered`. You can see the bluetooth.service is stopped & started. That is because I've added a script to do that after hibernation because I thought it can solve the problem. Without doing that, the symptom is the same.

```
un 15 18:26:01 ubt bluetoothd[35322]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jun 15 18:26:01 ubt bluetoothd[35322]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt bluetoothd[35322]: Terminating
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt bluetoothd[35322]: Stopping SDP server
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt bluetoothd[35322]: Exit
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Succeeded.
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: Starting SDP server
Jun 15 18:26:02 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jun 15 18:26:03 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jun 15 18:26:03 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:24 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:56 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 15 18:26:56 ubt bluetoothd[36505]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
```

Comment: This isn't a solution but a workaround per https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170653/bluetooth-mouse-stops-after-a-few-seconds
If you left click the mouse starts straight away sometimes (I tested it when reading that question and it worked perfectly but testing it again here it's not so there must be more or it could be my mouse which has been dropped probably too many times