# Keyboard and mouse stop working after 8 minutes

Tags: drivers, apt, usb, keyboard, android-studio

After a recent package update (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`), Ubuntu 20.04.2 has started consistently disconnecting my USB mouse and keyboard after about 8 minutes. By disconnecting I mean they're losing power and inputs aren't sent. I know they're losing power because they're both LED and all the lights turn off.

I've tried recovery mode and fixing broken packages, reverting to an older version of my Nvidia driver, and `sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`, none of which have any effect.

Is there a way to figure out which packages were recently updated so I can revert them?

I am dual booted with windows if that means anything.

*Edit: after the devices turn off, only a reboot will fix them. They do not wake back up after using them like they do when the computer went to sleep*

*Edit 2: This only happens when Android Studio is open... too bad that's all I'm using right now :/*

Comment: possibly related https://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I should clarify, they never turn back on, and they both go off at the same time. I have to reboot to get them back. I'll try this out when I get back to my computer.

Comment: there has been posted two bug reports related to usb over the last few hours not sure if relevant,https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1956857 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1956849

Comment: Hmm, I'll try reverting my kernel as well. I bet that second report is the problem

Comment: Not powernap or powertop, neither are installed

Comment: Reverting the kernel didn't work. Did find out it's only Android Studio that causes it to freeze, so that's something... If I never open it, the devices never turn off