# Scripts for hybrid graphics discreete card disable on startup

Tags: scripts, hybrid-graphics, privileges

A lot of time ago I've used a simple script in /etc/rc.local to disable discrete graphics during bootup.
But now it's not allowed to do anything with /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch when you not logged in as root (I can use it only after "sudo su"), so the script can not do anything.
Any ideas how to escalate privileges or simply how to make it work?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Ah, /etc/rc?.d/* scripts doesn't work this way too.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/20578/6969

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

`chmod -R 705 /sys/kernel/debug`

`chown -R $YOURUSERNAME:$YOURUSERNAME /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo`

`echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`

in my `rc.local` and it works often for me (not always though).

Comment: seems to work randomly for me too, have you figured out why?

Comment: no, sadly I have not. Are you using an AMD ATI card?