# Help needed in understanding this command?

Tags: command-line, vgaswitcheroo

```
echo OFF | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

In one of the questions in this forum, someone had posted this command to switch off graphics card to save power consumption and this worked like a charm almost reducing my battery consumption to less than half of what it consumed before.

The contents of sys/kernel/debug/vgawitcheroo/switch file are

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
```

I want to know what this command actually does, the significance of vgaswitcheroo/switch file and what is the piping that is happening in the command. Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `echo OFF | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` writes `OFF` to the special "file" `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`. For details on the difference with `echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`, see [Redirect the output using `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/q/20578/6969)

Entries in `/sys` are special. Those are not real files but an exported interface from the kernel space. In this case, `vgaswitcheroo` is an interface to the switcheroo code that can be used for toggling the power on hybrid graphics systems. More details on this can be found in the Ubuntu help pages: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics#Using_vga_switcheroo.

If you are interested, the source code where this interface is exported is at http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.4/drivers/gpu/vga/vga_switcheroo.c