# Why can not change the file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward?

Tags: filesystem, process

```
$ sudo echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Permission denied
```

then I try to get write privilege, also failed.

```
$ sudo chmod a+wx /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
chmod: changing permissions of `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward': Operation not permitted
```

what is wrong?

Comment: should use $ sudo bash -c "echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"

Comment: related: [Redirect the output using `sudo`](http://askubuntu.com/q/20578/127745)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied)

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to change the kernel values. Be sure of what you are doing.

Okay here is how you can change the value of **ip_forward** with root privilege (`sudo -i`)

- First check the value of ip_forward using command: `sysctl -a | grep ip_forward`
- Now using `sysctl -w <parameter=value>` you change the value of ip_forward:

  - `sysctl -w ip_forward=1`
- Make these changes to reflect in kernel using: `sysctl -p`
- Do the first step once again to check the values.

I recommend you to go through the [man page of sysctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/sysctl.8.html)

Comment: On newer installs it's `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` with the full namespace

Answer (score 1):

Edit file /etc/sysctl.conf and edit this section:

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

to

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 (remove # sign)
```

then type command: `sysctl -p`
Last, reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

To change this kernel value in kernel version 4.4+ (Ubuntu 16.04+), you need to do the following:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Answer (score -1):

Terminal:

```
sudo nano /proc/sys/net/ipv4 ip_forward
```

after change it, save with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and exit with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: -1 Text editors are a bad way to edit kernel parameters since they're not real files even though they look a lot like them.