# How to solve "permission denied" when using sudo with redirection in Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

When using sudo to allow edits to files, I regularly get 'permission denied'.

For example, my mouse is jittery and sluggish, so I want to disable polling:

```
sudo echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N">/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```

I'm prompted for a password, and then get:

```
bash: /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf: Permission denied
```

So I tried to do a temporary change to disable polling by using:

```
sudo echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
```

Yet again the system responded with:

```
bash: /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll: Permission denied
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Output redirection (via the `>` operator) is done by the shell, not by **echo**. You have to login as root

```
sudo -i
```

Then you can use redirection

```
echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
```

Otherwise you can run bash string with sudo

```
sudo bash -c "echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll"
```

Comment: You can't run echo with sudo? the what about the result I got: `saji@laptop:~$ sudo echo "Hi"
[sudo] password for saji: 
Hi`

Comment: you can write on file, echo "something" > somewhre. It's using pipe.. That is the problem.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case, then please update your answer to reflect that running echo is a problem in that case only.

Comment: You can't simply run the shell builtin `echo` as sudo, unless you do something like `sudo bash -c 'echo …'`; however, POSIX systems usually supply an external `echo` command such as `/bin/echo` on OS X, which sudo can execute without rigamarole. Thus, the `echo` command you usually run and the `echo` command you run with sudo are probably two different, but similar commands.

Comment: If that is the case, why did the answers to this question suggest echo?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/840431/high-cpu-usage-for-kidle-inject-x-in-ubuntu-16-10

Answer (score 88):

The output redirection is done by the shell *from which the command has been invoked*. So, breaking everything into bits, here what is happening*:

- shell invokes `sudo echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N"`, which executes `sudo` command with `echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N"` command line
- sudo asks for a password, opens superuser shell and invokes `echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N"`, which runs `echo` command passing it `"options drm_kms_helper poll=N"`
- echo, running with `root` privileges, prints the string to its standard output.
- `echo` command terminates, superuser shell exits, `sudo` terminates
- the shell from which the command has been invoked collects the output and tries to redirect it to `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf`, which is writeable only by root. It gets "permission denied" error.

For the ways to fix this see @shantanu answer.

---

(*) - while the above sequence helps to understand why the command fails, in reality things happen somewhat out-of-order: the original shell notices the redirection and tries to open the file for writing before invoking the `sudo ...` command. When opening the file fails the shell doesn't even invoke the command which was supposed to write to the file (thanks to @PanosRontogiannis for pointing this out).

Here's a quick test:

```
$ touch ./onlyroot.txt
$ sudo chown root:root ./onlyroot.txt
$ sudo bash -c "whoami | tee who.txt" > onlyroot.txt
bash: onlyroot.txt: Permission denied
```

In the test above the `whoami | tee who.txt` was going to create a file named `who.txt` containing the word "root". However, when the output redirection fails in the calling shell, "who.txt" file is also missing because the command was not invoked.

Comment: More likely the shell 'forks' itself and tries to open /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf before trying to 'exec' sudo which means that the first 4 steps your describe never actually happen because the file cannot be opened.

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis: thanks, I've updated the answer

Comment: I upvoted but IMHO the (\*) has to be replaced with the first part of the answer and then the first part can be used as a simplification in the (\*) part for those who might need it.

Answer (score 73):

You can use a [`tee`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee) command like this:

```
sudo tee /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll <<<10
```

Or if its a command's output:

```
echo 10 | sudo tee /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
```

If you had a situation where you wanted to append rather than overwrite the target file--that is, to make `tee` behave like `>>` rather than `>`--you would use `tee -a`.

Comment: +1 logging in as root is a bad idea for manual work, and a *really* bad idea for scripted tasks.

Comment: Also, `sudo tee /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll > /dev/null` if you don't want it printing to `stdout` as well.

Answer (score 19):

An approach I haven't seen mentioned here is to simply execute the entire commandline in its own shell. The `sudo` manpage itself gives an example of this approach:

> To make a usage listing of the directories in the /home partition. Note that this runs the commands in a sub-shell to make the cd and file redirection work.

```
$ sudo sh -c "cd /home ; du -s * | sort -rn > USAGE"
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use a temporary file. This is useful in a bash script.

```
temp=$(mktemp)
echo "Hello, world!" > $temp
sudo cp $temp /etc/wherever
```

Answer (score 5):

**`sudo dd of=`**

To append as you want:

```
echo inbytes | sudo dd of=outfile oflag=append conv=notrunc
```

or to recreate the file from scratch:

```
echo inbytes | sudo dd of=outfile
```

Advantages:

- nicer than `tee` since no `/dev/null` redirection
- nicer than `sh` since no explicit subshell (but an implicit one for the redirection)
- `dd` has many powerful options, e.g. `status=progress` to see transfer progress: [How to show the transfer progress and speed when copying files with cp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/how-to-show-the-transfer-progress-and-speed-when-copying-files-with-cp/824895#824895)

Works because sudo forwards stdin to the command.

Comment: This is good. We think of `dd` as how we overwrite our once-great filesystems, and don't realize it's for mundane tasks too--and that other commands as root also cause great harm if used on on the wrong files/devices. [Like `sudo tee`](https://askubuntu.com/a/230517), `sudo dd` will of course also work with [here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings), e.g., `sudo dd of=outfile <<<'hello world'`. [Thanks for editing. NB with `sh -c 'cmd'`, `sh` is a subprocess that's a shell, but not really a subshell except in the sense *all* external commands begin as one.]

Answer (score 1):

Create a one-line script from your command, then execute the script as `sudo`. For example:

1. Use an editor to create a file; for example:

   ```
   nano my_script.sh
   ```
2. In the editor, insert your shebang, and the command:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash  
   echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N" > /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
   ```
3. Save the file & exit the editor; e.g. `~/my_script.sh`
4. Make the file executable:

   ```
   chmod 755 ~/my_script.sh
   ```
5. Run the script under `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo ./my_script.sh
   ```