# Edit the bind file of a module

Tags: usb, kernel

I am trying to bind a usb device, which is a wifi adapter, to the module manually, but when I try to edit (as root) the bind file in /sys/bus/usb/drivers/mt7610u it returns this

```
sudoedit: bind: Input/output error
```

The permissions enable root to write, here they are

```
-rwxr-xrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:55 bind
```

How can I get around this, or is there any other method of binding the device to module?

Comment: have you followed this: https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/  or tried the (unaccepted) solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/575882/binding-device-to-a-driver-module

Comment: yea I did both of them, it's the same, doesn't allow me to edit, input/output error