# upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10 issue

Tags: upgrade

During the distro-upgrade 14.10 in the unpacking I saw an error in the terminal that said do this to fix:

```
gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
```

However I get a permission denied message every time even when I try that using `sudo` in front.  When I run `sudo apt-get update` I notice

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgbm1 xorg
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

How do I get these to upgrade?

Comment: This is not, in fact, specific to those particular versions.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/614005/ for an instance of this same thing when upgrading from version 14.10 to version 15.04.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

This is, very simply, a mis-use of `sudo` on your part.  The redirection in the command

```
sudo gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
```

is enacted by the shell and **happens before** the `sudo` command is executed with superuser permissions.  So the shell tells you that permission is denied when attempting to overwrite the contents of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache` because **it is** to you, the unprivileged user doing redirection in xyr unprivileged shell.

The correct ways to enact the fix that the message is giving are:

- To do this in a superuser shell.
- To quote the redirection and pass it to a secondary, privileged process, shell:

  ```
  sudo sh -c 'gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache'
  ```

For what it's worth, the underlying cause of this problem is reportedly an error in the "maintainer scripts" for the gdk-pixbuf package that causes it to delete the cache file partway through the upgrade process.  This error has persisted through several Ubuntu versions.

## Further reading

- [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/)
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=625203#40
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdk-pixbuf/+bug/1282294/comments/7