# How can I install brasero in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, brasero

As Brasero dropped out of the core apps in 16.04, I tried to install `brasero` via APT but with no luck

```
sudo apt-get install brasero
```

The response tells me that there is no package brasero.

Brasero isn't found in the new Gnome Software either :-(

Do I need a specific PPA or this just because 16.04 is still beta?

EDIT:
For some reason the universe repository was not ticked in **Applications & Updates**. See answer below for the solution.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/brasero says its in universe.

Comment: @Fabby : Yes, the problem was the missing universe repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably repository issue, Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` doesn't contain what is needed.

```
sudo echo "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brasero
```

For more informations You can check this article:
 http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/brasero

---

Edit:

If you're using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Live CD, you can check the Universe checkbox in "Software & Updates" (second one in screenshot) from the "show applications" menu.
[image: Universe Checkbox]

Comment: Note: http://askubuntu.com/q/230476/158442, and not everyone is in the Czech Republic :D

Comment: Not quite sure where our OP is from, im not from Czech tho, thats the 1st repo-link ubuntu web poped me up with :P What did You mean about that command line? I'm used to use it like this on debian or just `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` :P

Comment: `sudo echo … > /some/file` won't work. On Debian, I'd expect you're running around as root, which is why the redirection might work. The linked post explains why `sudo` is ineffective here, and the workaround.

Comment: Ah yes, that may be quite issue tho. I added my user to sudoers just to speed stuff up when i do need it, so right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing similar problems after executing this command

```
sudo apt-get install brasero

Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

then please do

1. `sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
2. Now update list with `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install brasero with `sudo apt-get install brasero`

Work for me Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I used Synaptic's    worked like a charm

system > Admin > Synaptic Package Manager

search brasero   rightclick brasero mark for install

click apply Thats it