# Having Boot menu issue with Ubuntu 18.04 installation

Tags: boot, uefi, 18.04, bios, livedvd

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 running in my laptop. I want to upgrade to 18.04, so I burnt a DVD with 18.04 ISO image and when I load the DVD and open the boot menu using F2 I could only see something like Ubuntu(ST ...)

I can't find DVD. So  I researched the internet and found that I need to enable Legacy instead of UEFI and also keep Legacy first in BIOS. So when I load the DVD and open boot menu, I can see DVD but when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a message pops in black screen and the DVD doesn't boot with 18.04

[image]
This is the message that pops up.

Comment: Didn't you try with USB stick? Since you already have 16.04 you can make a boot able USB with start up disk creator as a quick solution. Later you can think of this DVD why not working.

Comment: But why is it not installing via live dvd. I installed 16.04 using live dvd and it was installed fine.I just want to know how to deal with this ...

Comment: Can you try using `start up disk creator` to make the DVD as bootable.. I guess simply burning the iso image to DVD is not same as making a bootable DVD or bootable USB. The Pic you attached is not a error during installation part.. It did not find bootable DVD.

Comment: But i cant find article which creates bootable dvd using start up disk creator it is used only for making bootable usb.Please provide a link to make bootable dvd

Comment: Hi, https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu#0 this can be similar to 16.04 also

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/752976/install-brasero-in-ubuntu-16-04 this link may help to install brasero software.

Comment: Well that did work i burned the disk using brasero and it is worked.Can't figure out why the disc i burned in my windows desktop couldn't boot !!

Comment: burning and making bootable DVD's are different. brasero is the software which is capable of making bootable DVD in your case with Ubuntu. may be you have to find the similar app to make a "bootable DVD for ubuntu iso's" in windows.