# Keyboard backlight keeps going on in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: dell, 16.04, keyboard-backlight

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my **Dell Latitude E6540** and **my keyboard backlight** is **keeps going** on after some time even after I switch them off using the shortcut keys (Fn+->).
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: i don't know exactly if it was the update to 16.04 - but yesterday i noticed that my keyboard backlight stopped working - it will not light up :-(

Comment: hm got it to work again: first allow normal user to write to file: `sudo chmod a+w /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness` than set brightness to other value than 0 (0..9 are valid for me) `echo 9 > /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness`

Comment: Same happens to me (started recently) on Ubuntu 14.04.5.

Answer (score 12):

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Worked for me I have a new 2in1 Inspiron 7568.

Comment: This sets the light to level 2. Turning the light off can be done by echoing `0` into this file. But anyway - this does not answer the question posted here.

Comment: for thinkpad the directory is: `/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight` but I can't figure out what is triggering the backlight to turn on all the time

Answer (score 12):

Just purchased a 2016 Dell XPS13-9350. Wiped off Windows 10, with immense joy by the way, and installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the Cinnamon desktop. This is a sweet laptop combo.

The default setting is to dim the keyboard back light after 10 seconds of no key press. This was driving me absolutely crazy because I fly a lot and want the back light to stay on longer.

The file `/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/stop_timeout` contains the back light timeout value.

Answer 3 (above) did not work for me because the echo command did not work, even as root. Instead I did the following:

```
sudo nano /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/stop_timeout
```

change the `10s` on line-1 to `300s` (Without quotes). This will change the timeout to 5 minutes. Change it to whatever you wish.

Save the file (Ctrl-O, Enter, Ctrl-X).

Hope this helps someone as frustrated with this as I was.

Comment: If `sudo nano FILE` works, there's no reason why `echo ... > FILE` shouldn't work from a root shell. You probably ran `sudo echo ... > FILE` instead. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied. As such, your answer doesn't offer any improvement of the other answer.

Comment: I have been able to modify that file with nano but not with vim. Any idea why?
With vim I got this error when trying :w
"stop_timeout"
"stop_timeout" E667: Fsync failed
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: @Nisba I had the same problem with Neovim. I just used  `echo 5m | sudo tee ...` as the first one mentions, but with this answer's file name.

Comment: This worked for me. Amazingly, I find I am unable to delete the file, or write using vi - even via "sudo"...yet I am able to edit using nano!!! How wierd is that??

Comment: @fig @Nisba the likely reason is because vi wants to make a temporary file in that directory, and nano doesn't. You can still write with vi, but exit with `:x!` to override the complaint about the temp file.

Answer (score 3):

I found fix in [one of comments on launchpad bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1510344/comments/101)

*Step 1: change system option*

Edit file
**/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf**

change:

```
<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
       send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
```

to:

```
<deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
       send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
```

*Step 2: execute command with system startup*

add folowing lines to the file **/etc/rc.local**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# Mask kernel module
sudo systemctl mask systemd-backlight@leds\:dell\:\:kbd_backlight.service
exit 0
```

It is really works.

Keyboard backligt works too, but not automatically, by pressing Fn-keys only.

Comment: This worked for Dell Precision 7510 - Ubuntu 16.04.1. I have attempted other fixes but this seems to be the only one that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another thing on Dell laptops (including my XPS 15, 9550) is that the backlight dims and goes off after 10 seconds idling.

There is a command that worked for me (Linux Mint 18 on a 9550, kernel 4.8) that allowed me choose the timeout :

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "60s" > /sys/class/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/stop_timeout'
```

This is for a 60s timeout, which is sufficiant in my case.
Of course, you can put anything here, like 3600s for an entire hour, which can comfortably relate to « stay on ».

Comment: `cat /sys/class/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/stop_timeout` returned `10s` which is the default - in case any1 needs it

Answer (score 1):

I used to have my **Dell Vostro 3560** keyboard-backlight constantly turned on after reboot, even if I had it turned off. 
The fix was in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`. I changed `IgnoreLid=false` to `IgnoreLid=true`.
That helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem on Ubuntu 22.04.1 with Mate.

- Pressing `<Fn>+<Space>` is not permanent because Mate overrides the backlight setting when the screen is unlocked.
- Tweaking `systemd` does not help.

### Solution

I have solved the problem by doing the following:

1. Run `gsettings list-recursively | grep --color kbd` to find relevant settings. In the output, you will find these rows:

```
org.mate.power-manager kbd-backlight-battery-reduce true
org.mate.power-manager kbd-brightness-dim-by-on-battery 50
org.mate.power-manager kbd-brightness-dim-by-on-idle 75
org.mate.power-manager kbd-brightness-on-ac 100
```

2. Change `kbd-brightness-on-ac` to `0` and `kbd-backlight-battery-reduce` to `false` by running:

```
gsettings set org.mate.power-manager kbd-brightness-on-ac 0
gsettings set org.mate.power-manager kbd-backlight-battery-reduce false
```

Now the keyboard backlight will stay off when you unlock the screen.