# My laptop keyboard backlight keeps turning on every time when I boot it up

Tags: software-installation, dell, laptop, keyboard-backlight

I am new to Ubuntu environment, can someone help me? Even though I have disabled the backlight using the function key but no luck...
Also, I have checked the BIOS settings and shows that the keyboard illumination settings are disabled.
If there's a solution, please explain in detail. Thanks.

My Laptop spec:

Dell Vostro 5568

Using Ubuntu 16.04 Lts

Comment: The best answer in my case was here. https://askubuntu.com/a/916499/318507