# How to turn keyboard backlight off after x time of inactivity?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, asus, backlight

I have Asus ROG GL-752 notebook and I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1. I suffered until I almost died from many driver issues, especially with Nvidia, but with some struggle I managed to make things to work properly.

After spending all the day trying to find fixes, I still struggle from one driver. Previously under Windows 10, the OS installed by the manufacturer originally, the backlight turns off automatically after some seconds or maybe minutes of inactivity. Once a button is hit, the backlight turns on again. Under Ubuntu, the backlight doesn't turn off, except if I turn it off by hotkeys `fn` + `f3`.

I have a similar issue as this user: [Keyboard backlight keeps going on in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763552/keyboard-backlight-keeps-going-on-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

My wishful thinking had me wandering in this path:

```
/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/power
```

where I found a file named `autosuspend_delay_ms`, my gut tells me this is the thing that needs to be fixed, I don't really know. The file is empty when opened via `nano` as a root user.

*How to automatically turn off the backlight of the keyboard after x time of inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard backlighting problem was finally fixed for me in 17.04 on my Toshiba Satellite. You might try updating to 17.04, or at least booting to the Ubuntu Live DVD 17.04 and see if it works for you.

Comment: I update my distro to 17.04, didn't help. backlight turns of only once the screen is locked  `Super` + `l`

Comment: Guess what, this broke my sound driver :(. Ah! And now I just fed up fixing things, I'm going to reinstall 16.04 and make a script for they keyboard.

Comment: Why don't you just stick with 17.04 and fix your sound problem. Does it occur everywhere, or just with certain apps. They did make a change with alsa vs pulseaudio audio subsystems.

Comment: This is not a distro issue, not at all. I installed Fedora just to make my hardware compatible. But Fedora failed miserably for my hardware, this is a hardware problem.  Even with Ubuntu 17.04 things didn't go well after I upgraded, I had to reinstall some packages. The graphic card in Ubuntu works perfectly fine, after some efforts of course! But now I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  it's stable at the moment for my machine.  I'll be writing a script to fix the keyboard problem and maybe post it here.