# Unknown image appearing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: indicator, notification, 18.04, keyboard-backlight

I am having the following appear and disappear in the middle of my screen after a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04:

[image: Half-full image]

It alternates with one whose bottom bar is "full".

I don't know what this is, and I would like to stop it.

Comment: That is the Keyboard Backlight Brightness indicator.  Maybe this might help:  https://websiteforstudents.com/disable-enable-ubuntu-18-04-lts-desktop-notifications/

Comment: Turning off notifications sometimes seems to work, but often the changes don't survive a reboot.  And sometimes turning off notifications doesn't help at all.  Does anyone have any more ideas?

Comment: Since it is still a new OS, it sounds like a bug.  You might want to file a bug report https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a workaround: https://askubuntu.com/a/916499/823243 .  It does mean that the backlight can no longer be turned on at all: but I don't care.

Comment: Well, according to that fix they are claiming that the backlight works after performing those steps.  Maybe there is a possibility that whatever they are blocking might be a double of something built in causing the problem.  I don't have a laptop to test this out on or I would be more than happy to try for you.