# How to create etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: command-line, repository

The sources.list repository file simply doesn't exist because of an installation issue, causing all sorts of problems because all the commands like .deb and stuff return command not found. What is the easiest way to fix this?

note: I'm not trying to re-write a corrupted sources.list, but rather to create one. If I was trying to re-write, it would let me use some commands that have been suggested in other posts, but because the current condition of the sources.list is "nonexistant," the other commands return "sources.list was not found and thus cannot be rewritten."

Comment: You can find a prisinte unchanged `sources.list` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16220097/)

Comment: What other commands? My answer's command creates a `sources.list`; it doesn't check for existing ones (if there are any, they are overwritten).

Comment: hmm you are right. The error when you do your error's command is in fact different. It is as follows:

Comment: Permission denied.

Comment: This doesn't help much though.

Comment: @thecat are you root? The command assumes you're root. And see http://askubuntu.com/q/230476/158442

Comment: thx for the help- however the problem was actually my ubuntu version. On a chromebook, precise wasn't loading properly from my chrouton, hence the missing sources.list. Switching to trusty seemed to fix it.