# What are the disadvantages of continuing to use Ubuntu 14.04 while newer versions are available?

Tags: upgrade, updates, lts

Other than the fact that updates are supported only till 2019, is there any reason why I shouldn't keep using 14.04 while upgrades to higher versions are available?

Comment: You'll be missing latest cutting-edge softwares

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no disadvantages of continuing an older but still supported release of Ubuntu, like 14.04. It will be supported until April 2019, so you can go on running it for more than 2 more years without worrying.

Of course the latest official release will experience slightly more love regarding fast package/update maintenance and it may have additional new features, but security updates will always be distributed to all supported releases as fast as possible. It might take minimally longer until hardware enablement packages, new kernels and other updates that mainly introduce new features and no serious bug fixes get backported to older versions, but this should not be a disadvantage.

The advantage of having not the very latest Ubuntu release installed but a slightly older LTS (long term support) version is that all software is much more stable here as it has been tested for longer time.

To conclude, you do not have to upgrade unless you want to. Some non-critical software updates might not be available for your older release, but as long as it's still supported, there's not really a problem.

Comment: Hello, I cannot ask anymore questions and it says that it's because I have asked questions that have had bad reputation (like this one I guess). So I need to know how I can delete this question.

Comment: or maybe get rid of the negative votes to this.

Comment: @Harsha Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/135565 for more information about the automatic question ban that seems to have been applied to you.  Additionally, we have revised your post a bit and gave it some love. I actually don't understand why it was downvoted that much anyway... That's all I can do for you currently.

Comment: I need help regarding something else.
When I type in "sudo echo "blacklist intel_powerclamp">/etc/modprobe.d/disable-powerclamp.conf" in the terminal, I get "'bash: /etc/modprobe.d/disable-powerclamp.conf: Permission denied".

I need the reason for this.
 Also, I need to know how I can revert back to enabling the intel_powerclamp if I need it.

Comment: Your question is already answered here: http://askubuntu.com/q/230476/367990

Comment: Sorry for making you search that. I couldn't find an answer myself though! Thank you.