# Fish shell as default

Tags: fish

I'm trying to become the root on my terminal with `sudo -i` command, but the system display `sudo: /usr/local/bin/fish: command not found`. I tried to set the fish shell as default, but I got a problem. Could anyone be able to tell me what I could do to fix the problem?

I tried to set fish shell as default with first `sudo echo /usr/local/bin/fish >> /etc/shells` and after `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish`. However, it looks like I have more than one `usr/local/bin/fish` file in `/usr/shells`. (In fact, I followed from  [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453236/how-to-set-my-default-shell-on-mac))

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** I know now the file is not `usr/local/bin/fish`, but `usr/local/bin`. I've succeeded to set fish shell as default, but I'm still having the `sudo -i` problem.

Comment: You're gonna have to give us a little history. How did you set it as default? How did you install it?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Ok, it's done

Comment: Those are instructions for macOS. You are on Ubuntu, right?

Comment: Yes, I am with Ubuntu. However, It seems that procedure also work in Ubuntu (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453236/how-to-set-my-default-shell-on-mac).

Comment: I think you're getting that error because Ubuntu doesn't have `fish` installed by default. You need to use `sudo apt install fish`.

Comment: Yes, I did that. It is indicated `chsh: /usr/local/bin/fish is an invalid shell
`

Comment: I doubt `apt` would have installed it to `/usr/local` - more likely `/usr/bin/fish`. Also `sudo echo ...` to write to `/etc/shells` isn't going to work - see [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied)

Comment: @steeldriver I'll try to localize `fish`

Comment: Ok, now I've succeeded to set up fish shell as default, but I'm still having the problem of `̀sudo: /usr/local/bin/fish: command not found`.

Comment: What's the output of `which fish`, `grep fish /etc/shells`, and `getent passwd root | cut -d: -f7`?

Comment: @SandraRoss, I encountered that error message, and I think my answer below solves that problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace a bad default shell for `root` with `fish`:

1. Install `fish` (with `sudo apt install fish` if you want Ubuntu's package)
2. Run `sudo nano /etc/pam.d/chsh`
3. Insert a `#` in front of the line `auth       required   pam_shells.so`
4. Save and exit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
5. Run `sudo chsh -s $(which fish)` (remove the `$` if you're doing all this within `fish`)
6. Run `sudo nano /etc/pam.d/chsh`
7. Remove the `#` you inserted
8. Save and exit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Now, you can test that the shell is set properly with `sudo -i`.