# sudo -i problem - sudo: /bin/bash/asd: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

Whenever I use the `sudo -i` command in the terminal, I get:

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for user: 
sudo: /bin/bash/asd: command not found
```

The `/bin/bash/asd` was just some mistyped directory I entered previously.

Even after restarting and clearing the terminal history, `sudo` keeps giving me this error.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to me right now while testing that what can be the cause of the problem and sure it is because of a non-existent shell being set as `root` default shell.

I couldn't run any command with `sudo`, I wasn't able to run `sudo -i`, `sudo -i /bin/bash` or even `sudo su -`, because there is no `/bin/bash/asd`.

The only thing that I could do and it worked was running:

```
sudo -s /bin/dash
```

to get shell with root access, `sudo -s /bin/bash` should work too.

Then use `nano` to edit `passwd` file:

```
nano /etc/passwd
```

you should see a line look like this:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash/asd
```

change it to :

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>to save the file.

Now use `exit` command to get out of `dash` shell which has`root` access.

You are done, however I suggest running:

```
sudo chsh root -s /bin/bash
```

to make sure permissions are correct.

Comment: So I did what you suggested and when I do 
    sudo chsh root -s /bin/bash
I get chsh: PAM: Authentication failure.

Comment: Yes it does, you are not able to just run: `sudo chsh ...` to change the root shell becasue `sudo` does not work correctly right now as I described you should change `/etc/passwd` file manually. read my answer again; also Pay attention to the answer, I didn't say to change root shell to `/bin/bash/` I said change it to: `/bin/bash` :-)

Comment: Ok so I reread your solution and it does indeed work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it was helpful, you're welcome ;)

Comment: There's also [an alternate way to bypass the `chsh` errors](https://askubuntu.com/a/848038/616451).