# How do I overcome "permission denied" when using sudo?

Tags: permissions, files, sudo, echo

I’m using Ubuntu 14.04.  I’m having trouble clearing out a file.  I’m getting permission denied even though I’m using sudo.  Here’s what’s happening …

```
myuser@mymachine:~$ sudo chmod 755 /var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log
myuser@mymachine:~$ sudo echo '' > /var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log
-bash: /var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log: Permission denied
myuser@mymachine:~$ ls -al /var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rails root 304746186 Dec 31 15:08 /var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log
```

What evil demonic possessions have taken over and how can I conquer this crazy file?

Comment: With `sudo echo '' > /var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log`, you're running the `echo` command as root but redirecting its output as your own (non-root) user. See [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied).