# private/strongswanKey.pem: Permission denied

Tags: sudo, ipsec

I am trying to create a certificate based tunnel but when I type this line:

```
sudo ipsec pki --gen --type rsa --size 4096 --outform pem > private/strongswanKey.pem
```

it returns me `private/strongswanKey.pem: Permission denied`. 
what should I do?

Comment: See [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied)

Comment: it worked using `sudo -i`. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "permission denied" when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash)