# Ubuntu 14.04 Permission denied when trying to get OpenVPN

Tags: networking, server, permissions, vpn, openvpn

**System info:**

Distributor ID: Ubuntu | Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS | Release: 14.04 | Codename: trusty

**Problem:**

I am having trouble. I am trying to get openVPN and I am following this guide here: [Link to guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04).

I have successfully done the first two commands, but when I do this code:

`gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz > /etc/openvpn/server.conf`

I get an error: `bash: /etc/openvpn/server.conf: Permission Denied.

Can anybody help? Feel free to ask for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write into the /etc/ directory without using `sudo`.  The guide omits this little fact in many cases.  Notice the first command `apt-get update` which also won't work without `sudo`.  I think the guide assumes you are logged in as root.

Modify the command as follows:

`gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz | sudo tee /etc/openvpn/server.conf`

Comment: I did instead of gunzip, I did sudo sh and still got the same error but I haven't done it with gunzip. Thanks, i'll try it.

Comment: See [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied?)

Comment: The redirection (`>/etc/openvpn/server.conf`) is done while parsing the `sudo ...`, and is owned by the non-`root` user. `gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz | sudo tee /etc/openvpn/server.conf >/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo -i
```

After that, try

```
gunzip -c
```

again.