# cannot change file content owned by me (system file)

Tags: permissions, files, system

I'm trying to change content of system file, buy without success. 
chown by me. i 
m able to open and save file, but once o open again, it resets.

```
echo 5>/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od
```

gives no error, but file stays the same.
as far as i get file used by the system.

Please advice how to change it. thanks.

I want to build script to change couple files from same directory.

thanks

Comment: @chazecka You can not redirect so easily with sudo.

Comment: I see, I have just tried it myself, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not change ownership or permissions of system files, doing so can break ubuntu. Most are owned by root and keep them that way.

Second, if you have not already, read up on permissions and sudo

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

These are important for security issues.

Third, rather than editing these files you can usually edit a configuration file somewhere.

Fourth run from a root shell:

```
sudo -i
echo 5>/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od
```

And fifth, if you want to redirect with sudo use tee or similar

```
echo 5 | sudo tee >/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od
```

See [When using sudo with redirection, I get 'permission denied'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied) for details

Comment: i played around to get it working. ill get back permissions.
TEE option didnt helped. tried already. 
i need to change these files, there is no configuration for it.

Comment: If it is not working you need to post the command you ran. Also we need more details

Comment: both options not working. 
used exactly as you wrote:
sudo -i
echo 5>/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od
same result. file not changed

Comment: files are from amd video driver. holding setting values i need to change.
i found that some people did managed to change it with ease. i cant

Comment: is there some mode that will not use those files so i could change them?

Comment: So identify your card and explain what you are trying to do. The redirect methods I gave you work, but may not be the way to change your settings.

Comment: rx570 amd
trying to change memory and cpu clock values (and i know that's possible)