# Permission Denied on laravel/homestead when writing file in after.sh

Tags: vagrant, laravel

I have added the following lines to my laravel/homestead after.sh in an attempt to install and enabling ioncube when provisioning the box.

```
wget http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz

tar xvfz ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz

sudo cp ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so /usr/lib/php/20131226

cron='zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/20131226/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so"'

sudo echo "$cron" > /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/00-ioncube.ini

sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart php5.6-fpm.service
```

however upon provisioning I keep getting permission denied errors on the sudo echo "$cron" > /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/00-ioncube.ini line.

I have tried changing the way that I write to the file (using cat ) but all report the same error. I have checked and it is reporting that the user is 'vagrant' which if I run the commands via CLI run correclty with permissions.

What do I need to do?

Comment: See [How to solve “permission denied” when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

the following now works for me

```
sudo -i

wget http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz

tar xvfz ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz

sudo cp ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so /usr/lib/php/20131226

sudo bash -c "echo 'zend_extension = \"/usr/lib/php/20131226/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so\"' > /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/00-ioncube.ini"

sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart php5.6-fpm.service
```

not sure if the sudo -i is necessary at the start