# Three problems with Ubuntu 20.04 under Windows WSL

Tags: suspend, sudo, gcc

When using 'gcc' -Os option not accepted

`sleep` command produces `sleep: cannot read realtime clock`

Can no longer perform:

`sudo cat XXX >> YYY`

Results in `Permission denied` where XXX and YYY are owned by root

Comment: I'll  expect `sudo cp XXX >> YYY`  to fail since cp needs a destination operand instead.

Comment: When using 'gcc' -Os option not accepted. Sleep is a separate issue sleep command produces sleep: cannot read realtime clock. Sorry I meant to say  sudo cat XXX >> YYY

Comment: sudo cp  XXX >>YYY should have read  sudo cat XXX >> YYY

Comment: In `sudo cat XXX >> YYY`, `sudo` was attached to the `cat` not the text redirection. That's why permissions were denied. See [How to solve “permission denied” when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks. I ended using  cat AAA | sudo tee -a BBB >/dev/null That works across platforms like Ubuntu, Debian, Linux Mint at the suggestion of a friend.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What errors do you encounter while running `gcc -Os`? As of now it seems you're asking 2 questions in a single question which might make this question too broad. Consider asking one question in a post.

Comment: At this point I am using   gcc -s  instead of  gcc -Os  -Os was supposed to be for size optimized.  And yes , there were two different questions.

Answer (score -1):

Under Ubuntu 20.04    gcc -Os  for optimize for size does not work am using  gcc -s

and cat issue has been fixed with    cat AAA | sudo tee -a BBB >/dev/null

And the shell 'sleep' command not working on WSL turned out to be a 'libc' issue.