# Permission for all commands, but unable to clear cache

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, cache

I am trying to clear the cache on my laptop running:

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
          Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-40-generic
```

However when I put in these commands this is the output:

```
$ sudo sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
$ sudo sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
$ sudo sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

However when checking my permissions I get this:

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for [MY USERNAME] on [COMPUTER NAME]:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin
User [MY USERNAME] may run the following commands on [COMPUTER NAME]:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

It would appear that I can run all commands. Why is this happening, and is there a fix?

I have also replicated the issue in root.

Comment: Related: [How to solve “permission denied” when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running `sync` with `sudo`, but not the shell's redirection of the `echo`. Instead do:

```
sudo sh -c 'sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

or

```
sudo sync; echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null
```

Comment: @KevinWilkins accept that answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks for the reminder!