# How do I make an html file with text in it in a separate directory from the one I'm in, all in one command?

Tags: command-line

Is it possible to create an html file with some text already in it, (I'll just use my name as an example) in a directory separate to the one you're in, all in one command? I'm very new to Ubuntu and any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output), which creates a file if the given target does not exist (or overwrites the file if it does, so do be careful). Instead of the output of a command being written to the terminal, it gets written to the target file.

```
echo "something" > target
```

So, replace `target` with the path to the file you want to create, and `"something"` with what you want to put into the file...

```
echo "zanna s" > /home/zanna/playground/new-file
```

The directory has to exist already, and you must have permission to write there. If you do not, `sudo` will not help you, because redirection is done by the shell itself, and the shell is not being run as root. There are [ways around that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash), though. One of them is `tee`, which is another option for you (although perhaps this makes it two commands). The `tee` command writes to both standard output (the terminal) and the specified file, so it is a little more informative than using redirection:

```
echo "various things" | tee /path/to/file
```

This `|` thing is a "pipe". It turns the output of the command to the left of it into the input of the command to the right of it. So the output of `echo` (`various things`) becomes the input of `tee`.

One can make `echo` give multiline output using the `-e` option, although it is pretty awkward:

```
zanna@peach:~$ echo -e "things\non\nseveral\nlines\n" | tee playground/new-file
things
on
several
lines
```

In the above command I used a relative path to the file (a path that depends on the current location). `playground` is a subdirectory of the current directory, so this works fine. If you use the absolute path (for example `/home/zanna/playground/file` or `~/playground/file` or `$HOME/playground/file`) the same command will work no matter what the current working directory is.

I don't know what you mean by a html file. Perhaps it should just have an extension:

```
echo "$USER" | tee ~/subdirectory/file.html
```

Comment: It might be useful to mention that redirection can (and I think does, by default?) overwrite the target file if it already exists. That could definitely give some people unhappy surprises.

Comment: @DavidZ yes it does do that - it truncates the file to zero bytes before writing anything (so one may empty a file (or create an empty file) by doing just `> file`). I will mention it just in case.

Comment: This answer could be improved by mentioning `printf` as a safer, more portable and more powerful alternative to `echo`. Also, `set -C` (with a capital `C`) or `set -o noclobber` will prevent `>` from overwriting an existing file.  (These are specified in POSIX and they work in bash.) Also, since the user is “very new”, an example of a relative pathname beginning with **`../`** might be especially helpful.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' feel free to write an answer. I don't want this one to be longer and more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

To bypass `echo` being awkward at multiline literals one can use another bash feature:

```bsh
cat > /path/to/my_file.html << EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You just wrote `echo HTML` file with $SHELL as user ${USER}!</p>
    </body>
</html>
EOF
```

Note that EOF can be any string as long as it does not appear on separate line in your input. Also note that some of bash constructs like backticks and variable substitution are still in effect.

If you are doing this interactively as opposed to using in script, editor like `nano` might be better suited for this job.

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy that file in another directory?

```
cp <filename> <path/to/new/directory>
```

or if you want to create a new file into another directory...

```
nano file.html /path/to/new/directory
```

you write whatever you want to write...

then to edit or write something new in that file

```
nano /path/to/new/directory/file.html
```