# How to create files with sudo so that the files is owned by root?

Tags: permissions, 20.04, files, sudo, root

I just confused to create file with sudo command. As i know, sudo command is commonly used for root privilege(by default) and when i created files using command below:

```
sudo cat > root.txt
```

And i saw the user, it still regular username not root. How that can be happen? and how to create files owned by root without changing user to root?

Comment: No not root privileges. Admin privileges. root is just another admin.  " and how to create files owned by root without changing user to root?" you do realize this is 1 way? you can then do nothing with the file unless "others" has executable rights on the file?

Comment: It's because your unprivileged shell creates `root.txt`, then runs `cat` with `sudo`. See related [How to solve “permission denied” when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stream redirection (`> file`) takes place in the parent process (running as `$USER`) **before** the command (`sudo`) even begins.

You can either use a different command:

```
sudo tee root.txt
```

or, afterwards, change the ownership of the file:

```
sudo chown root:root root.txt
```

Comment: You'd need something like `: | sudo tee filename` else `tee` will block waiting for input

Answer (score 4):

Redirection is 'outside' of `sudo` in your example. Try

```
sudo bash -c "cat > root.txt"
```

Comment: ... or simply `sudo touch root.txt`, which avoids redirection altogether