# Unable to enable SRIOV for a Ethernet port

Tags: networking, virtualization, network-bridge

I get a permission denied error when I run the command

```
sudo echo '7' > /sys/class/net/eno99/device/sriov_numfs
```

This is the error:

```
bash: /sys/class/net/eno99/device/sriov_numfs: Permission denied
```

I have enabled SRIOV in the following ways:

1. Enable Virtualization in System Setup.
2. Enable Global Sriov in System Setup
3. Enable Sriov for each ethernet port separately.

Still I am getting the same error. Also cannot find any critical error in `dmseg` that may cause the problem.

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot]

I also tried

```
sudo echo 7 | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eno99/device/sriov_numfs
```

[image: Second command attempt]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. I don't know what Sriov is, but if your command requires root permission using redirection like that [won't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash). Instead try `echo 7 | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eno99/device/sriov_numfs`. If that does not work, please update the question with the results.

Comment: @Zanna Still getting the same error. Updating the question

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix This does not works either

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's working now don't know Why it didn't before.  I used the following commands 1. sudo -i      2. echo 4 > /sys/class/net/eno2np1/device/sriov_numvfs