# bash: permission denied, Owncloud helper script

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, owncloud-server

I don't know to much about linux and server creating but I wanna create my private owncloud web drive, I have linux Ubuntu 20.04 server on my Raspberry pi4 installed. I have started using this [tutorial](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/10.8/admin_manual/installation/quick_guides/ubuntu_20_04.html#create-the-occ-helper-script) to set it up but I'm having issues at the beginning.
When I'm trying to create **Helper Script**(?):

> #### Create the occ Helper Script
>
> Create a helper script to simplify running occ commands.
>
> ```
> FILE="/usr/local/bin/occ"
> /bin/cat <<EOM >$FILE
> #! /bin/bash
> cd /var/www/owncloud
> sudo -E -u www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/owncloud/occ "\$@"
> EOM
> ```
>
> Make the helper script executable:
>
> ```
> chmod +x /usr/local/bin/occ
> ```

In my terminal I get this kind of error:

[image: Terminal screenshot]

How make it work?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/occ` is owned by root. The article clearly mentions, ***"This guide assumes that you are working as the root user."*** You may consider logging in as `root` temporarily or `sudo` (note that sometimes `sudo` may not work, for example, with shell builtins).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting for commands and command output, please.

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy, the tutorial uses ubuntu, where 'root' isn't usable directly, it then assumes you have logged in as root.

Either wrap the code in another script and run that with sudo, or extract the three lines for the script from the code and create the script directly with an editor. If you do the latter, remove the '' from the last line i.e. "\$@" becomes "$@"

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a permission denied error, you can try this instead:

```
FILE="/usr/local/bin/occ"
sudo tee "$FILE" <<'EOM'
#! /bin/bash
cd /var/www/owncloud
sudo -E -u www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/owncloud/occ "$@"
EOM
```

This will run `tee` with `sudo`, which should allow writing to the `/usr/local/bin/occ` file. (See [How to solve "permission denied" when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/230476/158442)) Then you can use the `chmod` command with `sudo` as well.