# Best Practice for Always Logging Into Root

Tags: permissions, sudo

The answer in [How to solve "permission denied" when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash) says to use "sudo -i". Is this always going to make sure I have write permissions for every file and every program launched from terminal being able to edit any file I want? Because I am trying to edit the UI to something more to my tastes, it seems I really need to be digging deep into this distro and I keep running into permission denials repeatedly. Ubuntu 22.04 or whatever was the latest stable version as of a week ago.

Comment: The answer is Yes

Comment: Best practice is to never log in as root, but use `sudo` to get elevated privileges only when needed. `sudo <cmd>` gives elevated privileges for that one command, `sudo -i` starts a (login-) shell and you will have elevated privileges until you exit that shell. Please read `man sudo` for further details.

Comment: Textbook [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): In comments, you finally revealed that what you are REALLY trying to do is edit the Firefox Snap. Snaps are provided on a read-only squashfs filesystem; even root cannot edit those read-only files. The actual solution for you is to not use the snap. Use a deb or the upstream installer to create Firefox files that you CAN edit.

Answer (score 3):

You asked two questions:

##### Question #1

> Is this always going to make sure I have write permissions for every
> file and every program launched from terminal being able to edit any
> file I want?

Is clear and can be squarely answered ... Assuming writable(*not read only*) file system … The answer is, simply, yes.

`sudo` runs commands as the user `root` ... try:

```
whoami
```

versus:

```
sudo whoami
```

The option `-i` logs you in to that `root`'s login shell specified in the `/etc/passwd` database so you become `root` until you enter `exit` or terminate the shell ... This, however, means that `root`'s login-specific resource files such as `.profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell.

Please see [`man sudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/sudo.8.html):

> **-i, --login**
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login
> shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login
> will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell
> for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an
> interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts to change to that user's home
> directory before running the shell.  The command is run with an environment
> similar to the one a user would receive at log in.  The Command environment
> section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the
> environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.

##### Question #2

> Because I am trying to edit the UI to something more to my tastes, it
> seems I really need to be digging deep into this distro and I keep
> running into permission denials repeatedly. Ubuntu 22.04 or whatever
> was the latest stable version as of a week ago.

Is too broad and lacks details and can't be squarely answered as is ... so I suggest you move this part to a new post and provide more details.