# Help me to develop a .sh script to start a simple task

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to connect to a server through AtlasVPN automatically.

```
@user: $ atlasvpn connect
1 - Standard
2 - Streaming
3 - SafeSwap
4 - MultiHop
*(IT IS NOT ANOTHER LINE)* Enter a number corresponding to the desired category: 1
1 - Netherlands - Amsterdam
2 - United States - New York
3 - Hong Kong - Hong Kong
4 - United States - Dallas
5 - United States - Los Angeles
6 - Singapore - Singapore
7 - Finland - Helsinki
8 - Norway - Oslo
9 - New Zealand - Auckland
10 - Argentina - Buenos Aires
11 - Hungary - Budapest
12 - Denmark - Copenhagen
13 - Germany - Frankfurt
14 - Bulgaria - Sofia
15 - Sweden - Stockholm
16 - United States - New Jersey
17 - Netherlands - Amsterdam
18 - UAE - Dubai
19 - Serbia - Belgrade
20 - Japan - Tokyo
21 - United Kingdom - London
22 - United Kingdom - Manchester
23 - France - Paris
24 - Poland - Warsaw
25 - Latvia - Riga
26 - Ireland - Dublin
27 - Estonia - Tallinn
28 - Czech Republic - Prague
29 - United States - Las Vegas
30 - Slovakia - Bratislava
31 - Austria - Vienna
32 - United Kingdom - London
33 - Italy - Milan
34 - Spain - Madrid
35 - Canada - Montreal
36 - Turkey - Istanbul
37 - Brazil - Sao Paulo
38 - United States - Miami
39 - Mexico - Mexico City
40 - South Africa - Johannesburg
41 - United States - Phoenix
42 - Israel - Tel Aviv
43 - Chile - Santiago
44 - Thailand - Bangkok
45 - Belgium - Brussels
46 - Albania - Tirana
47 - Taiwan - Taipei
48 - Romania - Bucharest
49 - Switzerland - Zürich
50 - Portugal - Lisbon
51 - Australia - Sydney
*(IT IS NOT ANOTHER LINE)* Enter a number corresponding to the desired server: 38
You have successfully connected to United States - Miami.
@user:
```

1. This type of code does not work:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> atlasvpn connect
> 1
> 38
> ```

Because "Enter a number corresponding to the desired category:" and "Enter a number corresponding to the desired server:" are in the same command-line.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "permission denied" when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash)

Comment: No, it does not have to do with the question.

Comment: This might work: `echo -e '1\n38\n' | atlasvpn connect`

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question doesn't appear to be related to the Ubuntu OS. You'll likely be better served by working with the [Unix & Linux community, as this is a common bash question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For these types of tasks, look into `expect` scripts.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it like this:

```
#/bin/env expect

spawn atlasvpn connect
expect {
    "Enter a number corresponding to the desired category:\r" {
        send "1\r"
        expect {
            "Enter a number corresponding to the desired server:\r" {
                send "10\r"
                interact
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it´s doesnt work.
It asks for the first value and then times out.