# Why i am get error trying install openvpn

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to install openVPN on Ubuntu, but I'm facing difficulties.

I confirm that the system is up to date:

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

Install the necessary packages:

```
apt install ca-certificates wget net-tools gnupg
```

I add the local repository for installation:

```
wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Run the following command:

```
echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian focal main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
```

But this command gives me the following error:

```
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list: Permission denied
```

And when executing the command for installation: `apt install openvpn-as` It gives me the following: `E: Unable to find package openvpn-as`

```
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list: Permission denied
```

Comment: You've provided no base OS/release details; but `/etc/` is a system directory which you can usually read most contents there, but need to elevate privileges to write there (ie. `sudo`)... so check your command which you didn't provide for us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "permission denied" when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash)

Comment: You tried to install openvpn-access-server not the community edition. You should probably remove the ppa and uninstall the packages then try again, unless you want to install the access server, it’s a bit easier to setup.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have been misled by some random internet instructions. You DON'T need to add any sources or run mysterious commands to install OpenVPN.

Your output suggests that you added some unnecessary source. Remove it. Undo anything else those instructions told you to do. Return your system to stock condition.

On a clean Ubuntu system, installing OpenVPN as simple as `sudo apt install openvpn`...but your system isn't currently clean due to whatever instruction you followed.