# How to use sudo with pipelines?

Tags: command-line, scripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sudo & redirect output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20578/sudo-redirect-output)

Let's say I want to add some line into /etc/profile.
I try:

```
$ sudo echo "something" >> /etc/profile
bash: /etc/profile: Access forbidden
```

Of course I could write:

```
$ sudo su
# echo "something" >> /etc/profile
```

and this works, however it does not work within a shell script.

So, what is the right way?

Comment: imho, it is better to run the whole script as root rather than have `sudo` commands in it.

Answer (score 19):

**Your version:**

`sudo echo "something" >> /etc/profile`

In this command, `echo` is run as root, but the shell that's redirecting `echo`'s output to the root-only file is still running as you. That's why you are getting "Access forbidden"

**Working version:**

`sudo bash -c 'echo "something" >> /etc/profile'`

In this command you use sudo to start a new shell with root privileges and then give that shell the whole command string (including the redirection) with the -c option of bash.

Comment: Ok it works. Can you explain me why this works, while my command does not work?

Comment: Done. Hope my explanation makes sense to you.

Comment: @ororo Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: More generally, this is also how to run a pipeline `foo|bar|zip` within sudo: `sudo bash -c 'foo|bar|zip'`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `tee`:

```
$ echo "something" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
```

If you omit the `-a` (append) the file will be overwritten.