# Script not having permission to write into /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, scripts, ip

Hello I have to write a script with the name `setip` that can be run like this:

```
./setip <ip> <mask>
```

and that must set the IP address to `<ip>` and the mask to `<mask>` on the `lo1` interface.
Below is the content of my script, but it when I try to run it I get the error
"permission denied".
What is wrong with my script and how should I proceed ?

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
sudo echo 
"
auto lo:1
iface lo:1 inet static
address $1
netmask $2" >/etc/network/interfaces
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo echo "  
auto lo:1  
iface lo:1 inet static  
address $1  
netmask $2" | sudo tee /etc/network/interfaces
```

The last line on your script `netmask $2" >/etc/network/interfaces` attempts to edit the interfaces file which only root can write to. (Or at least it should be owned by root)
However, `sudo echo "" >` likely does not work how you want it to.

What it's doing is it is executing `echo ""` with root permissions, but the `>` operator is not executing with those permissions.

You may want to reformat your command along the lines [of this example.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20578/redirect-the-output-using-sudo) In this case, the command that outputs to the file is being run as root, while the other commands do not have to be.  I've shown you an example of that above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `sudo` is doing what you think it's doing.  What's actually going on is that `sudo` is only affecting the `echo` command - it won't actually output what you need to the `/etc/network/interfaces/` file because `sudo` doesn't actually cover the `>`.

So what can you do?  You have two options:

1. reformat your command to work like the one provided in the link from robobenklein in their answer.
2. Run the entire script with `sudo` which would effectively run the entire command as superuser and the redirection might work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `chmod +x setip` to allow your script to be executable. More information on file permissions can be found [here](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/).